# React Router v3 address bar not updating correctly when clicking link quickly

Tags: javascript, webpack, react-router

My application uses `react-router` v3. We use WebPack to asynchronously load chunks on a route change (via dynamic `import` statements).

Under certain conditions, clicking `<Link/>`s too quickly will cause the address bar to not update (perhaps due to clicking faster than the WebPack chunk can resolve?).

The issue appears sporadically and is *correlated to high network latency*. Higher network latency (such as 3g) increases the chance of the issue arising.

Example route config:

```
{
    component: App,
    indexRoute: controlsRoute,
    childRoutes: [
      {
        path: "app/account",
        getComponent(_discard: void, cb: Function) {
          import("./account/index") // WebPack dynamic import
            .then(module => cb(undefined, module.Account))
            .catch((e: object) => cb(undefined, crashPage(e)));
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

`<link/>` usage:

```
<Link to="/app/account" onClick={props.close("accountMenuOpen")}>
  {t("Account Settings")}
</Link>
```

**Are there any common mistakes that cause React Router to lose track of state when loading WebPack chunks asynchronously?**